# updating the mysql table with php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

```
$.ajax({
            url:"update.php",
            data: {orderid:orderid,date:date,tool:tool,name:name,email:email,count:count,orderstatus:orderstatus},

            type:"POST",
            dataType: "text",
            complete:function(response){

                console.log(response.responseText);
            }

        });
```

the above code ajax sending the data(name, date, email) to different file name update.

the update.php is as follows

```
$orderid=$_POST["orderid"];
        $date=$_POST["date"];
        $tool=$_POST["tool"];
        $name=$_POST["name"];
        $email=$_POST["email"];

        $count=$_POST["count"];
    $sql = "UPDATE $tablename SET  `Tool`= '$tool', `Request Date` = '$date', `Name` = '$name', `Email` = '$email', ` Country_Entered` = '$count'WHERE `Order ID` = '$orderid'";
```

but for some reason the update is not working when i add  `Country_Entered` =$count` i tried to debug the problem i can not find the under lying problem in the code

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

        if ($result) {
               echo "Successfully Updated.";

        } else {
               echo "Some Error occured.";


  echo  mysqli_error($sql) ;

        }
```

the `echo  mysqli_error($sql) ;` is displaying the following error error

> "Unknown column ' Country Entered' in 'field list'"

and can any one pick up on the problem?

name, email, count, tool, orderstatus are varchar,
and orderid is int,
req date is DATE.

Comment: check browser console for debug and what you getting?

Comment: No space between '$count'WHERE.. If this is not the problem match the datatype against table fields and it'd be better if you add the table structure in the problem.

Comment: remove unwanted space from query `` Country_Entered` = '$count'WHERE` shoul be `Country_Entered` = '$count' WHERE

Comment: What checks are you doing on the posted fields? What escaping are you doing? Is it MySQL injection that is causing the issue? But yes there is a simple typo

Comment: @LiamSorsby newbie alert. cannot understand.

Comment: @qtpseleniumSupport http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php use prepared statements, do not just insert your variables into SQL otherwise you are leaving yourself open to attack

Comment: @RakeshSharma don't worry about that in my program their are plenty of spaces between $count and WHERE. i had to reedit the format to post on stackoverflow

Comment: if you want to show mysqli_error you shoud pass database connection object to it not your sql query so     "echo  mysqli_error($sql) ;"   is not correct and you should use  mysqli_error(/* here your database obj */); to can see your error

Comment: In the javascript, what is `count`? Can you do a `console.log` of the variable please? Can you also do the same in the php script - do a `var_dump` of `$_POST['count']`. You may find that the value is not being set correctly.

Comment: @babakfaghihian worked thank you following is the error "Unknown column ' Country Entered' in 'field list'" whatever that means

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King 'count' value is coming into the update table but mysql error is coming   "Unknown column ' Country Entered' in 'field list'"

Comment: Are you sure that you are entering the correct date format in `Request Date`? I guess it must be of format `2015/02/01 00:00:00`

Comment: @Cyberpks the problem is not with req date but with count the above code working fine if I get rid of  ` Country_Entered` = '$count'

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the exact mysqli error anywhere. Can you add it in the question?

Comment: Use `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);` where you return custom message for error i.e. in place of `echo "Some Error occured."` to see the actual error message

Comment: @Cyberpks  "Unknown column ' Country Entered' in 'field list'" this is the error i am getting

Comment: @qtpseleniumSupport my friend check the name of the field in your database exactly and copy that exactly in your query i think you have make a mistake in writing field name Like country_entered and something like this

Comment: @qtpseleniumSupport and finally you have a blank before your field name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, also mentioned by [@Rakesh Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878888/rakesh-sharma) in comments

> "Unknown column '[**blank space**]Country Entered' in 'field list'"

I think the problem is an extra space in `' Country_Entered'` there is extra white space in the query. Remove that and I think it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that varchar columns take non-empty values such as empty string, or null. Problem happens whan your query looks like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE $tablename SET  `Tool`= '$tool', `Request Date` = '$date', `Name` = '$name', `Email` = '$email', `Country_Entered` = '$count'WHERE `Order ID` = '$orderid'";
```

For example if your $count is empty, your query will look like this

```
... `Country_Entered` = '' ...
```

it's sql syntax error.
Please note that space in your column name -> ` Country_Entered` = '$count'. Remove that just to be sure it doesn't cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does the column Country_Entered really exist inside the DB?